# How to shift to a particular menu item by default for Bottom Navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am building an app with a bottom navigation bar that has  `app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"` file linked. As soon as the activity starts by default, the first menu item (Ex: Home Icon) gets selected. **What should I do to change the selected menu item as soon as the Activity starts?**

I am working with SharedPreferences. Fragments are loading properly but the respective icons for the fragments are not loading. By default, the icon for the home fragment gets focused in the bottom navbar.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseUser user;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "Dock";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();



        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 1);

            if (idName == 1){
                handleFrames(new ChatFragment() );
            }
            if (idName == 2){
                handleFrames(new GroupFragment() );
            }
            if (idName == 3){
                handleFrames(new SearchFragment() );
            }
            if (idName == 4){
                handleFrames(new FriendsFragment() );
            }
            if (idName == 5){
                handleFrames(new SettingsFragment() );
            }


        }
        handleOnClickListner();
    }

    private void handleFrames(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private void handleOnClickListner(){
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.chat:
                        handleFrames(new ChatFragment());
                        editor.putInt("idName", 1);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.groups:
                        handleFrames(new GroupFragment());
                        editor.putInt("idName", 2);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.status:
                        handleFrames(new SearchFragment());
                        editor.putInt("idName", 3);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.friends:
                        handleFrames(new FriendsFragment());
                        editor.putInt("idName", 4);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.setting:
                        handleFrames(new SettingsFragment());
                        editor.putInt("idName", 5);
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(resId);`

With this you can Set the selected Item in the script itself in OnCreate or any other function.